# Jquery queue/ .stop() problems

Tags: jquery

I am having some problems using `.stop()` to prevent functions from queueing up. If I use `.stop()` or a variation thereof the function dies after `hover:out` and will not restart.

You can see my code and the source here: http://joepolitic.com/zkmpract.html. Only the last menu item (c) has the `.stop()` on it, the rest have don't have it yet.

```
$('li.contact').hover(  
 function() {  
  $(this).stop().toggleClass('li contactb', 800);  
 },  
 function() {  
  $(this).stop().toggleClass('li contactb', 800);  
 }  
);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO :) Please post the relevant parts of your code in your question. A live link is nice but StackOverflow aims to be as self-sufficient as possible.

Comment: sorry about that I added it thx!

Comment: [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) is not an animation method and is not supposed to take a delay argument. Are you using a plugin that provides that feature?

Comment: @Frédéric it appears to be part of jquery ui

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the way that `toggleClass` works with a duration.  During the animation the `height` is being set directly on the element.  Once the animation is complete the `height` is removed and the class is added.  When you `stop` the animation pre-maturely, the `height` remains directly on the element which overrides the css class.  This is why it appears to just not work because adding and removing the class does not affect the height if there is an inline style.

The only way I can think to fix this would be to not use `toggleClass` and use `animate` directly.  If you don't want to set the initial height, you can just save the height in `data` prior to animation and pull it out when you want to set it back:

http://jsfiddle.net/yCAYw/1/

```
$("div").hover(function(){
    var $this=$(this);

    $this.data("height",$this.height());
    $this.stop().animate({"height":"200px"},1000); 
},function(){
    var $this=$(this);

    $this.stop().animate({"height":$this.data("height")},1000); 
});
```

Comment: I found here a better solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576365/jquery-problem-with-stop-and-delay-within-animation

Comment: @eveevans that is not the same question and why would you downvote me?  Using `stop(true,true)` would be ugly in this case as it causes it to jump.