# JQuery problem with stop() and delay() within animation

Tags: jquery, animation, queue, delay

As you can see on http://jsfiddle.net/FrelCee/5zcv3/4/ , i want to animate those 3 divs when the container is hovered.

Problem is this ugly queue that appears when you fast hover more than once.
I also tried using **.stop()** function, but then the **delay()** isn't working.

Here is an example with stop() function and delay() problem :  http://jsfiddle.net/FrelCee/FHC99/22/

Does anyone know any better way to this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to supply at least the first parameter to `.stop(true, true)` to clear the current queue and you can decide if you also want to supply the second parameter to jump to the end of the animation when the next one starts (that's up to you as it gives a slightly different effect).  You also need to place the `.stop()` calls before the `.delay()` so you aren't clearing the `.delay()`.  See the jQuery [doc for `.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to understand the two parameters for `.stop()`.  When I do that here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/pYgQr/, it seems to handle fast hover in/out just fine.

```
// On hover function
var hover = $('#container');
hover.hover(function(){

    $(this).find('#first').stop(true, true).animate({left:10}, 600);
    $(this).find('#second').stop(true, true).delay(100).animate({left:10}, 600);
     $(this).find('#third').stop(true, true).delay(250).animate({left:10}, 600);

}, function() {

    $(this).find('#first').stop(true, true).animate({left:-100}, 600);
    $(this).find('#second').stop(true, true).delay(100).animate({left:-100}, 600);
    $(this).find('#third').stop(true, true).delay(250).animate({left:-100}, 600);

}); // on mouse out hide divs
```

---

Also, I don't know why you're doing this at the beginning:

```
var hover = $('#container');
$(hover).hover(function(){
```

You can either do this:

```
var container = $('#container');
container.hover(function(){
```

or this:

```
$('#container').hover(function(){
```

---

In addition, there is no reason to do:

```
$(this).find('#first')
```

These are ids which must be unique in the page so it's better to use:

```
$('#first')
```

This will be faster in jQuery because it will be able to just use `document.getElementById('first')` internally.

Comment: When you fast hover, those divs are flashing (they return to left:10 instead of left:-100)... Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: You can see if you like it better with it this way `.stop(true, false)` instead of `.stop(true, true)`.  Those two options create slightly different looks when one animation is interrupted by the next one, but both will end up in the right place.  You can see this alternate effect here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/9QDue/.

Answer (score -2):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/5zcv3/5/

you don't have to use both `delay` and `animate`, just give `animate` different speed; the effect is similar

based on my experience, `stop` is a must

Comment: Giving different speeds isn't at all the same effect as delay.

Comment: did you care to try those 2 jsfiddles?

Comment: Yes, and while in the example the 3 divs slide in the same speed but just start at different times, in your jsfiddle all the divs start at the same time and slide in different speeds. You are right the divs will still reach their position in the same times, but this is still different.

Comment: Great, this might do the work. Any other idea will be appreciated.